# document.createEvent fails

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The following code fails (in JavaScript console, and also when injecting a script via browser extension)

```
document.createEvent('TestEvent')
```

Firebug spits out:

> [Exception... "Operation is not supported"
> code: "9"
> nsresult: "0x80530009 (NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR)"
> location: "http‍://www.google.com
> Line: 71"]

Chrome gives a similar error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent):

> `type` is a string that represents the type of event to be created. Possible event types include "UIEvents", "MouseEvents", "MutationEvents", and "HTMLEvents".

So you probably want:

```
var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
e.initEvent('TestEvent', true, true);
```

See [`event.initEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initEvent).

**Update:** Maybe `document.createEvent('Event');` is even better for custom events, but it is part of DOM Level 3 and I don't know how much supported it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these event types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent#Notes

`TestEvent` is not a supported event type. Better use "`MouseEvents`" or "`HTMLEvents`".

Answer (score 1):

There's simply no event type called `TestEvent`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent#section_4
http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-DocumentEvent-createEvent

Maybe you meant `TextEvent`?

PS: Next time do at least a bit of own research before using SO like you would use Google ;)

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom DOM event. Guess I have to do more reading.